# chrome-extension://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js error is shown at console while using Facebook SDK with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension which needs a Facebook login, but while using Facebook Javascript SDK I got this error "chrome-extension://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js". How to solve it? PLease help me out here.

Comment: Please provide more code, it would help much.

Comment: Please provide more details on the error. Code snippets would also be helpful.

Comment: (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
above is the Facebook SDK code and my app is working on "chrome-extension://hhpkiehapfnlomndfniikbfjnindbfel/index.html" URL that's why it is not matching the facebook connect URL.  And at console I got that error.